# How can I begin in setting up captive wifi portal?

Tags: wireless-networking, captive-portal

I'm planning to set a wifi captive portal in a small office, where; guests/employees will be directed to a portal page.  Employees must enter a user pass

Guests will be generated by a random code and use it to access the Internet. Both profiles are configurable (Example: Bandwidth capping)

Any suggestions how I can proceed on this project?  Been reading about 802.1x, radius, AAA

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) and specifically [Chillispot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot)

> ChilliSpot (chilli, chillispot) is a way to
>
> - Easily make the wireless or lan-connected computers display a 'landing page' on user's browsers.
> - Redirection occurs on the first web page, and until the user clicks through (I Agree/Login).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. ill go check it out and give feedback :)