# Xbox users bogging down my coffee shops open WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, blocking

I own a coffee shop with open Wi-Fi but the tenants that live above the shop are bogging it down with their Xbox. Is there a way I can block that device from connecting to my Wi-Fi?

Comment: Password protect your WiFi?

Comment: Well, presumably they want to continue running an open wifi.

Comment: If you'd like more specific instructions than the current ones I believe you'll need to share your wifi router's model information. Who is the manufacturer? What is the product identifier?

Comment: Running an open WiFi is just asking for this to happen. I know some kids who drive around looking for open WiFi so they don't have to pay for data. If you want it for customers only, you will need to password protect it. Simply let your customers know to ask if they want to use it. That is what our local coffee shop does.

Comment: Perhaps see: [How can I begin in setting up captive wifi portal?](http://superuser.com/questions/580920/how-can-i-begin-in-setting-up-captive-wifi-portal)

Answer (score 6):

You can block some of the ports that Xbox live uses:

@MC10 - has a good point, 3074 is Xbox only.

Also you can try a proxy.  Untangle (http://www.untangle.com/) is a great proxy/firewall/antivirus etc, that is easy to use with a GUI, is free, and can block BitTorrent protocol etc.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/networking/network-ports-used-xbox-live

I wouldn't block any of the well known ones such as 80.

I bet if you try blocking them one at a time, you will essentially block Live.

> Xbox Live requires the following ports to be open:
>
> - Port 88 (UDP)
> - Port 3074 (UDP and TCP)
> - Port 53 (UDP and TCP)
> - Port 80 (TCP)
> - Port 500 (UDP)
> - Port 3544 (UDP)
> - Port 4500 (UDP)

Comment: Don't block tcp\80 or udp+tcp\53, if you want your legitimate users to be able to browse the web. The others are more or less safe to bloick for anyone but an xbox user.

Comment: Actually, try just blocking [port 3074](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=3074) first. It looks like it's only used by games and Xbox Live. And yeah, definitely don't block port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Most routers will allow you to block individual MAC addresses, which you can get from the list of connected clients.  Be careful doing this, to be sure it's the offending gamers and not a random customer...

Comment: Also useful to note that this will only work if the xbox owners aren't very technical as changing or "spoofing" your MAC address is trivial. For xbox in particular, Under My Xbox, open the System Settings application.Navigate down to Network Settings. Select your Wireless Network. Select Configure Network. Select Additional Settings. Select Alternate MAC Address...and...bypass MAC filter until they you add a new one for the new MAC. Repeat.

Comment: You could also configure your router to provide a degraded experience for Xbox connections.  For example, you could enable Strict NAT, disable WMM (WiFi multimedia mode), and use an older connection protocol, like 80211a,b,g.  These will impact your other customers, too, and may be a bit self-defeating.  Perhaps a better alternative would be a) use a password that changes each day, and b) work things out with them, perhaps letting them use the connection after you close.

Comment: ahh @LanceLeonard I just realised I stole your suggestion and made it into an answer (I really should read *all* the comments first!)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you have for a router, but there are a few things that you can do.

People here have said bock ports, I would block every single outgoing port except 80, HTTP, 443, HTTPS, and 53, DNS; this way your customers are restricted to only browsing the web - no playing games, no torrenting, and no other unwanted traffic.

Change your WiFi password daily - print it on the customers receipt, that way at least the punks upstairs will have to buy something before they can use the WiFi that day (or only give it out to those who ask).

The thrid would be, depending on your router / access point, QoS (Quality of Service) where you can restrict every device to only use say, 1Mb/s download; this would allow every user to be connected, not affecting eachothers sessions.

DDWRT is an awesome open source router firmware upgrade (only available for some models) that allows you to do all of these things. You can even write a script that will change your password for you, and push it to another device for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the non-technical solution of having a conversation with them! Depending on your outlook on life! If you primary concern is knowing your internet is available for your customers during working hours then have a conversation and say you're looking into blocking them altogether, but if they respect that you're running a business and don't use your connection during those hours then you'll leave it be.

If your outlook on life is more of a get-off-my-lawn sort of thing, then the technical solutions above would be the way to go (I'm guessing this won't be the accepted answer ;) )